# Trying to understand layout constraints for iOS 9.3 support programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios9.3

I have a tabViewController with a navigatonController as tab 1. The root view of the navigationController is listView and selecting an item pushes a pageViewController onto the stack. The pageVC manages an array of the same viewController which has an scrollView with dynamic content and scrolls vertically. The scrollView is pinned to the anchors of the viewController with this code:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])
    }else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])
    }
```

I need to support iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3) devices.

The dynamic content in the scrollView and scrolling is all working as expected on iOS 11 devices with the content starting below the nav bar and scrolling stops at the top of the tab bar.

The problem I have is on iOS versions less than 11. The scrollView content is initially displayed correctly but if I tap or scroll the content, the top moves behind the nav bar and I cannot see the top of the scrollView anymore. The same for the bottom of the scrollView and the tab bar.

I have tried several stack suggestions for edgesForExtendedLayout, scrollView insets etc but can't find the right solution. I would ideally like to understand constraints, layout guides etc programmatically and any links to tutorials would be great for another day.

Comment: Just a comment - iPhone4s using iOS 9, something I used to support - is a *very* small piece of the full population. Or looking at this another way, iOS 9 (which for me introduced the ability to write `CIKernel` code) is supported on every phone from iPhone4s on. The 4s is the **last** 3.5 inch screen that I *used* to support. But since my apps are both universal and all orientations, I gave up on the 3.5 inch screen and decided to support iPhoneSE (4 inch) and everything since then.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in else

```
  let navBarView = self.navigationController.navigationBar

  let tabBarView = self.tabBarController.tabBar

  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBarView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBarView.topAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
```

Comment: This gives me layout errors when I scroll the content in the scrollView.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints with lots of "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint ...." for the top and bottom scrollView constraints.